# ComboBox value is not saving into sql server database

Tags: c#

Following is the image of the form. I want to insert the values and then load it from database but the comboboxes values doesn't inserted. Help me please...
Whats wrong with my code??

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPermissionID.Text) == true)
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UMSdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(per_id)+1 FROM Permission", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    {
                        if (dr.Read())
                        {

                            tbPermissionID.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@per_id", tbPermissionID.Text);
                            SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@fk_group_id", cbGroupName.SelectedText.ToString());
                            SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@fk_form_id", cbFormName.SelectedText.ToString());
                            SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("@per_save", cbSave.Items[cbSave.SelectedIndex].ToString());
                            SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("@per_update", cbUpdate.SelectedText.ToString());
                            SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("@per_select", cbSelect.SelectedText.ToString());
                            SqlParameter p7 = new SqlParameter("@per_delete", cbDelete.SelectedText.ToString());
                            SqlParameter p8 = new SqlParameter("@per_flag", cbFlag.SelectedText.ToString());
                            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Permission (per_id,fk_group_id,fk_form_id,per_save,per_update,per_select,per_delete,per_flag) VALUES ('" + p1.Value + "','" + p2.Value + "','" + p3.Value + "','" + p5.Value + "','" + p5.Value + "','" + p6.Value + "','" + p7.Value + "','" + p8.Value + "')", con);
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MessageBox.Show("Record Saved");
                            LoadPermissionDetails();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KevGI.png)

Comment: That is NOT how you use parameters.

Comment: These Parameters work fine with the Textbox value but not with comboboxs

Comment: No.  You ADD parameters to your Command object.  Right now, your query is open to sql injection and formatting issues.  Fix that query to say `VALUES (@per_id, @fk_group_id...` etc.

Comment: @LarTech Thanks bro... did it

Answer (score 0):

What kind of object have you set to the comboBoxes datasource? If it is a simple string array, try this instead of ComboBox.SelectedText:

```
ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

If your DataSource is not Array of Strings, you should cast the value of SelectedItem to you target type and then retrieve the property that you need to insert in database. E.g. if you assigned a list of Companies to the ComboBox and Company object has a property name called "Name", you should do something like this:

```
((Company)ComboBox.SelectedItem).Name
```

Remember to check if nothing has been selected to avoid **NullReferenceException**.

Comment: I have a combobox in which there are two Items "Y" and "N", Now i want to add the combox value to database through parameters ... I did every try with cbSave.SelectedItems.ToString();,cbSave.SelectedTextToString();,cbSave.SelectedValue.ToString(); but none of them work... and you've mentioned the Name property .. I didn't get it Bro...

Comment: I mentioned Name as a sample. If this is a practice, can you post your code somewhere so I can check what's the problem?

Comment: Offcourse bro its a practice... if you provide me your email it 'll be really appreciated

Comment: Why don't you create a repo on GitHub for it? It will be easier to see what's happening.